# How to retrieve an attribute as substring from a string in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have `<input id="text1" value="Stop1" type="text">`value saved as a string variable in VB.NET. I need to grab the value "Stop1" and save it in a string variable. What logic/function I should apply to extract "Stop1" from the string.

Comment: Why do you need such a logic? That seem to be prone to errors and cumbersome.

Comment: my str = <input id="text1" value="Stop1" type="text"> and I need to grab the substring "stop1" and save it in a new string variable. So that I can save just the "value" in the database.

Comment: Will this always be "Stop1" or will there be other data within value?

Comment: There can be any value and not just "Stop1"

Comment: Tim, you are right! my logic is wrong in the first place. I will try to get the value of the input box instead of saving the whole input box in the string

Comment: @FarhanHaque: Another hint: if this is really ASP.NET, i wonder why you don't use an ASP.NET `TextBox` for this. It has a `Text` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This extracts the entire data associated with `value`:

It assumes you have a string named `s` that contains your data.

```
'define the string id to find   
Dim idToFind As String = "value="
'find it in the string
Dim valuePos As Integer = s.IndexOf(idToFind)
'extract the part we want
Dim valueString = s.Substring(valuePos + idToFind.Length, s.IndexOf(Chr(34), valuePos) - valuePos + 1)
Dim valueStringNoQuotes = s.Substring(valuePos + idToFind.Length + 1, s.IndexOf(Chr(34), valuePos) - valuePos - 1)
Debug.WriteLine(valueString) 'Output: "Stop1"
Debug.WriteLine(valueStringNoQuotes) 'Output Stop1
```

If you plan to use this though you should think about adding some error checking to make sure the string actually contains the data you expect, check for upper/lower case etc etc

Comment: I already used your first answer which worked just fine! Thanks a bunch